# UIBarButtonItem appearance proxy setting font attributes not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

It seems like the iOS 11 appearance proxy mechanism for setting UIBarButtonItem font is not working completely. (It behaves as expected in iOS 10).

I want to know if this is a bug, or there is somehow a different way to do this.

My code:

```
NSDictionary *barButtonAppearanceDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:24], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor purpleColor]};
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Basically, the code appears to work, the button font is styled appropriately. However, when the user taps the button, the style reverts while the button is pressed.

Here's a video:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqgpbnlq6gw884p/UIBarButtonItem%20Interaction.mov?dl=0

To repro, create a new app using the Master-Detail app template. Add code snippet above in:

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Cool! Can you provide enough info so we can reproduce / test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to set the`Highlighted` style.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict UIControlStateHighlighted];
```